# guardar en cada variable un salto de linea php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente for

```
for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days")))
    {
        $string = dia_semana($i). "<br />";
        $rows = explode("\n",$string);
$unwanted = "SABADO|DOMINGO|-01-09";
$cleanArray= preg_grep("/$unwanted/i",$rows,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
$cleanString=implode("\n",$cleanArray);
echo $cleanString;
```

Esto me devuelve unas fechas y me omite lo que contenga SABADO o DOMINGO o incluso una fecha en especifico,

```
JUEVES 2019-01-03
VIERNES 2019-01-04
LUNES 2019-01-07
```

Debo registrar en cada campo de la bd los datos obtenidos por fila es decir:

teniendo los campos `dia1,dia2,dia3`

Se debe registrar en:

```
dia1 = JUEVES 2019-01-03

dia2 = VIERNES 2019-01-04

dia3 = LUNES 2019-01-07
```

Como logro ingresar en cada campo de la bd los datos obtenidos segun su salto de linea?

Comment: interesante.... alguna pregunta?

Comment: ah perdon no lo formule bien un momento

Comment: listo, ahora si

Comment: porque no haces otro `explode("\n",$cleanString);`

Comment: y esto para que?, acuerdate que debo registrar cada fecha en un campo de la bd

Comment: La variable `$cleanArray` contiene los valores que quieres guardar en los indices 0,1 y 2 o no?

Comment: asi es pero, cual es tu idea?

Comment: `insert into table values($cleanArray[0],$cleanArray[1],$cleanArray[2])`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113400/discussion-between-ernesto-jimenez-and-alanfcm).